# How do I get a quick and dirty recognition of possible typos in .net?

Tags: algorithm, string-comparison

I have to manually go through a long list of terms (~3500) which have been entered by users through the years. Beside other things, I want to reduce the list by looking for synonyms, typos and alternate spellings.

My work will be much easier if I can group the list into clusters of possible typos before starting. I was imagining to use some metric which can calculate the similarity to a term, e.g. in percent, and then cluster everything which has a similarity higher than some threshold. As I am going through it manually anyway, I don't mind a high failure rate, if it can keep the whole thing simple.

Ideally, there exists some easily available library to do this for me, implemented by people who know what they are doing. If there is no such, then at least one calculating a similarity metric for a pair of strings would be great, I can manage the clustering myself.

If this is not available either, do you know of a good algorithm which is simple to implement? I was first thinking a Hamming distance divided by word length will be a good metric, but noticed that while it will catch swapped letters, it won't handle deletions and insertions well (`ptgs-1` will be caught as very similar to `ptgs/1`, but `hematopoiesis` won't be caught as very similar to `haematopoiesis`).

As for the requirements on the library/algorithm: it has to rely completely on spelling. I know that the usual NLP libraries don't work this way, but

- there is no full text available for it to consider context.
- it can't use a dictionary corpus of words, because the terms are far outside of any everyday language, frequently abbreviations of highly specialized terms.

Finally, I am most familiar with C# as a programming language, and I already have a C# pseudoscript which does some preliminary cleanup. If there is no one-step solution (feed list in, get grouped list out), I will prefer a library I can call from within a .NET program.

The whole thing should be relatively quick to learn for somebody with almost no previous knowledge in information retrieval. This will save me maybe 5-6 hours of manual work, and I don't want to spend more time than that in setting up an automated solution. OK, maybe up to 50% longer if I get the chance to learn something awesome :)

The question: What should I use, a library, or an algorithm? Which ones should I consider? If what I need is a library, how do I recognize one which is capable of delivering results based on spelling alone, as opposed to relying on context or dictionary use?

*edit* To clarify, I am not looking for actual semantic relatedness the way search or recommendation engines need it. I need to catch typos. So, I am looking for a metric by which `mouse` and `rodent` have zero similarity, but `mouse` and `house` have a very high similarity. And I am afraid that tools like Lucene use a metric which gets these two examples wrong (for my purposes).

Comment: Don't ask for a library - see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Dukeling thank you for pointing out that my question was unclear. I know that recommendation of a "best" library is off topic. Now I edited the last sentence to make it clear that I am not asking for the community to choose a library for me, but to tell me how to recognize the libraries which meet my criteria so I can make the choice myself.

Comment: Please get rid of the word "synonym" from your question title and body -- as you finally clarify in your last sentence, that's not at all the problem you're trying to solve.  The problem you're trying to solve is (thankfully) much simpler: use the **Levenshtein distance** (which counts the minimum number of character changes, *insertions or deletions* needed to transform one string into another) instead of the Hamming distance, before dividing by the length of the longer string.

Comment: @j_random_hacker OK, edited it out and called it "alternative spelling" instead, hopefully it is clearer now. And yes, the Levenshtein distance is indeed a really good solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are looking to cluster terms according to Semantic Relatedness.

One (hard) way to do it is following [Markovitch and Gabrilovitch](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gabr/papers/ijcai-2007-sim.pdf) approach.

---

A quicker way will be consisting of the following steps:

1. download [wikipedia dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/) and an open source Information Retrieval library such as [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) (or [Lucene.NET](http://lucenenet.apache.org/)).
2. Index the files.
3. Search each term in the index - and get a vector - denoting how relevant the term (the query) is for each document. Note that this will be a vector of size `|D|`, where `|D|` is the total number of documents in the collection.
4. Cluster your vectors in any clustering algorithm. Each vector represents one term from your initial list.

---

If you are interested only in "visual" similarity (words are written similar to each other) then you can settle for [levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), but it won't be able to give you semantic relatedness of terms.For example, you won't be able to relate between "fall" and "autumn".

Comment: thank you for the input. "Semantic relatedness" is a good search term which helps me find a lot. As for Lucene, as far as I know it is primarily meant to index full text, and calculates similarity based on which words appear together, etc. I don't have full text, but a disjointed list of words. Do you think Lucene can work with this, and if yes, why? How do I recognize a tool which can  do it?

Comment: @RumiP. I suggest getting some full text, I recommended wikipedia for this purpose.

Comment: I don't care about full text. I have a concrete task to get done. It is to find all the mistyped or alternatively spelled words in an existing list of disjoint words. Learning how to find similar words in full text is a good skill, but it doesn't help me to do what I need to get done.

Comment: If you are not looking for synonyms and do not care to relate (example) "fall" and "autumn" you do not need semantic relatedness approach and can settle for levenshtein distance.

Comment: Thank you, levenshtein distance fits perfectly what I was looking for.  "fall" and "autumn" would have been nice to relate, but I don't have the data from which such similarities can be calculated, just the one list. And it would have been counterproductive to relate "autumn" and "season" too, which is what I think Lucene does.  If you put l. distance in the answer, I will accept it.